# Displaying data from API into WPF/C# into controls dynamically

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

Display data from API, into WPF application.

Hello, Im creating an application for a questionnaire. It calls the data from the API and i would like to know what is the best way to display the information.

The information displayed will have to be "questionnaire type" and will be attempted by users and saved into database with the selected values.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I already tried through textboxes that are dynamically created from a List, but setting the location of the textboxes tend to be full of errors

Please have a look at [`StackPanel`](http://wpftutorial.net/StackPanel.html)

> It stacks its child elements below or beside each other, dependening on its orientation.

With a stack panel you can place multiple elements atop of each other, see the sample from the link provided

```
<StackPanel>
  <TextBlock Margin="10" FontSize="20">How do you like your coffee?</TextBlock>
  <Button Margin="10">Black</Button>
  <Button Margin="10">With milk</Button>
  <Button Margin="10">Latte machiato</Button>
  <Button Margin="10">Chappuchino</Button>
</StackPanel>
```

this will result in the following layout

[image]

You can create these dynamically. Take the following template

```
<StackLayout x:Name="QuestionStack">
  <TextBlock Margin="10" FontSize="20" x:Name="QuestionTextBlock" />
</StackLayout>
```

and in your code behind

```
void DisplayQuestion(Question question)
{
    QuestionTextBlock.Text = question.QuestionText;
    foreach(var answer in question.Answers)
    {
        AddAnswerButton(answer);
    }
}

private void AddAnswer(Answer answer)
{
    QuestionStack.Children.Add(CreateButtonForAnswer(answer));
}

private Button CreateButtonForAnswer(Answer answer)
{
    var button new Button()
    {
        Content = answer.Text,
        Margin = 10
    }

    button.Click += (sender, eventArgs) => 
    {
        // handle button click
    };

    return button;
}
```

**Please note:** This is only *one* possibility. Without knowing more about your requirements it's hard to tell what you need exactly.

**Edit:**

Since you asked: You could for example create a custom control to display *one* question (I've replaced the `Button` with `CheckBox` and for sake of simplicity I've omitted the XAML, but it is not too hard to achieve the same results with XAML)

```
class QuestionControl : ContentControl
{
    private Question question;

    private StackLayout QuestionStackLayout { get; }

    public QuestionControl()
    {
        QuestionStackLayout = new StackLayout();
        QuestionTextBlock = new TextBlock()
                                 {
                                     Margin = 10,
                                     FontSize = 20
                                 };
        QuestionStackLayout.Children.Add(QuestionTextBlock);
    }

    public Question Question 
    {
        get
        {
            return question;
        }
        set
        {
            question = value;
            DisplayQuestion();
        }
    }

    private void DisplayQuestion()
    {
        QuestionTextBlock.Text = question.QuestionText;
        foreach(var answer in question.Answers)
        {
            AddAnswerButton(answer);
        }
    }

    private void AddAnswer(Answer answer)
    {
        QuestionStack.Children.Add(CreateButtonForAnswer(answer));
    }

    private CheckBox CreateCheckBoxForAnswer(Answer answer)
    {
        var checkBox new CheckBox()
        {
            Content = answer.Text,
            Margin = 10
        }

        checkBox.Checked += (sender, eventArgs) => 
        {
            answer.IsSelected = (sender as CheckBox).IsChecked;
        };

        return checkBox;
    }
}
```

You can now stack instances of `QuestionControl`. Since the `Answer`-objects are updated by the `CheckBox.Click` event you can simply access `QuestionControl.Question` to get which answers are selected. You might think about deep copying the `Question` when setting `QuestionControl.Question` instead of just setting the reference, to avoid side effects.

Comment: So let's say, i want to display, 1 label and 4 checkboxes( label: Question, 4 checkbox = Results) having 5 entries in my API will result in, 5 labels and 20 checkboxes.

Comment: In this case I would generate the stack layouts dynamically, too and put each question in one `StackLayout`

Comment: Or rather create a custom view to display *a single* question and then stack those custom views.

Comment: I've updated the answer with a more complete example.